# Unsafe cast issue, How to cast typesafe?

Tags: java, serialization

I don't see how I can convert the `Object` into an `ArrayList<Account>` as that I what I did serialize and it is of type `ArrayList<Accounts>`. As I see it this code should work.

Current de-serialize code:

```
ArrayList<Accounts> alst = new ArrayList<Accounts>();
try {
  ObjectInputStream ain = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("accounts.ser")));  
  Object o = ain.readObject();
  if(o instanceof ArrayList) {          
    alst = (ArrayList<Accounts>) o;
  }
  else {
    System.out.println("Big problem!!!");
  }

  ain.close();
}
```

I get the problem:

```
warning: 
[unchecked] unchecked cast
required: ArrayList<Account>.
found:    Object
```

I have read so many posts about this problem but I just can't get it to work on my issue. I have kept hammering on this issue for days and just no luck! I know this is the issue I am having with the file being de-serialized. How do I get it back into its former type from Object?

Is there any another way?

Comment: Put the ain.close into the finally statement or use Java 7: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: You can't do a typesafe cast here. The compiler can't know what type is stored in a file on the disk, and casting to `ArrayList<?>` would be onerous. Just suppress the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your trouble is not downcasting into `ArrayList`, but into `ArrayList<Account>`.

You can't downcast into a generic type without an *unchecked cast* warning. This is due to the core nature of Java Generics: at runtime there is no type parameter information associated with an instance. You will have to live with the warning, or suppress it with a `SuppressWarnings("Unchecked")` annotation on the method or expression.

Also, you seem to be confused about casts vs. conversions: a *downcast* (that's what you are doing there) doesn't convert anything, it just allows the object to be treated as if it was of the type you cast it into. Your object already is of the type `ArrayList`; your *variable* is of type `Object`. Please learn to appreciate these differences in Java, they are essential to comprehending and writing code.

Answer (score 1):

I think to avoid warnings you can do following thing:

```
  alst = (ArrayList) o;
  for (Object item : alst) {
    if (!item instanceof Account) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
  }
```